# How to debug proguard

Tags: android, debugging, proguard

On Android Studio I developped an app that nicely works on both emulator and real device.
Whenever I apply minification on proguard, with this gradle app configuration:

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

The app crashes randomly and frequently, always in different and unexpected moments, both on device and emulators. Unfortunately if I try to run the app and debug it from Android Studio, as stated in the documentation, the app is compiled and installed without proguard, and works perfectly.

So how can I find what's going on?

I found an answer to a similar question that states that I should configure proguard this way:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Is this the correct method, and if yes, how could I finally debug the proguard-ed apk?

Comment: As a humble suggestion, you should put a Crashlytics library in place to tackle these situations head-on

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        ...
    }
    release{
    ...
    }
```